# Don't have ADB.exe android

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

I've installed ADT bundle eclipse, and the problem is I can't run my project. It says

```
ADB server didn't ACK 
failed to start daemon
```

I've read a lot, people says type -adb kill-server and -adb start-server will helps, or go to processes tab and restart adb.exe, but the problem is, I don't know why I don't the adb.exe in my processes.

Can anyone help? Many thanks

Comment: open your task manager and end/kill adb.exe process. and restart your eclipse. hope it helps

Comment: no, its not even in my task manager, idk why..

Comment: try this, exit/uninstall (kill) any Mobile-PC Suite from our computer if they are installed.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows in cmd:

```
adb kill-server
```

For OS X in terminal:

```
killall adb
```

After that,restart eclipse and problem will be solved.

Also, check where is your path to adb.exe , is correctly located and can be executed.

Comment: it doesn't worked i get this message: adb server is out of date. killing... ADB server didn't ACK *failed to start daemon*